# What is v-mdl in vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

What is v-mdl (not v-model) in vue.js ? I have started working on a project and I am seeing v-mdl in some places as follows:

```
<div :id="id" v-mdl class="item" @click="toggle()">
```

Comment: you can probably figure this out by looking at what third party packages you have in your package.json and looking at their usage documentation

Answer (score 0):

`v-mdl` is probably an custom directive created in somewhere else.

You can find documentation about custom directives here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html